# How do I make a program "discoverable" on the network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

Hey guys, I was working on a simple chat program to brush up on my C#, and ran into a roadblock.  I wanted to allow one computer to broadcast its location, and the other to find that computer, and display it (and any others) in a list..  Just a push in the right direction would be great,
Thanks,
Max

Comment: By "network" do you mean a LAN, or internet? Or both?

Comment: "broadcast its location" is vague. please elaborate. you want it tied to the data link layer or the network layer?

Comment: @Jon I meant lan

@rockjock I don't know how to implement what I am looking for, the idea is to allow one computer to spot every other computer on the local lan that is running my program, list them, and allow my program to connect to the other computer using something like UDP.

Comment: Just found this:http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html  Looked good, but doesn't run on windows 7 (worked on xp fine though)..  Something similar to that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mono.Zeroconf](http://mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf) is a .NET library that provides common zeroconf opertations - service publish and discovery. It uses Apple's [Bonjour for Windows](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/index.html) as a transport on Windows.

Developers can publish services that will be exposed to other computers on the local network and also query the local machines on the network for services that could have been exposed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to share destination PC. and then run your web-based application on the target pc IIS.

---

Updated Part :

If you have awindows application and want users use that application youhave some solution

1. create a Login form for your application
2. use from MarshalByRef object and create a Channel between user andaplication
3. create a MSI (setup) and run it from server (in entire Active Directory).this will install one application in each client
4. create a simple dot net setup. justRight click onyour windowsproject in VS and then select Publich, in the wizard walk through creating a network application

I think the last option is closest one to your request

Comment: This is a desktop app, not asp.net

Answer (score 0):

See [Peer-to-Peer Programming with WCF and .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx).

Comment: Very interesting read, but everything about discovering is vista only, I was looking for a solution that could work on XP also.
Thanks though

Comment: @mazzzzz PRNP is supported on XP; the Advanced Networking Pack http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817778 is available for XP SP1 and is included in SP2 and later.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Name_Resolution_Protocol, it requires IPv6

Answer (score 0):

Use AD (Active Directory)? Or some such [which would serve as] central messageboard mechanism - maybe even MSMQ?